# What to expect when Airplane mode is enabled during wifi scan?

Tags: windows, winapi, wifi

I'm using windows WLAN APIs (Windows Desktop not Metro Apps) to scan WiFi networks.

I'm curious what will be the behavior of the WiFi scan when Airplane mode is enabled before the scan is completed? 
I'm trying to create such scenario but it very hard to catch such timing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking, "Airplane Mode" Takes the Radio Transmitters in your iPhone and changes their frequencies of transmission to frequencies that are sympathetic to Aeronautic Instrumentation, such as Guidance Systems for example.

Due to the frequency change, if you're scanning Networks and then you change the properties of the Network adapter, the adapter has to restart. So, your Scan will be temporarily interrupted.

Test it on your iPhone,  download something from App Store and switch modes during the download, see what happens. The Icon will suddenly stop and will display  "SEARCHING" and will then re attempt to pick up the connection again.